# build multiple sources with custom configure/make in RPM CentOS spec file

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I am working on CentOS 7. I need to make a RPM package. I have 3 tarball files like aa-1.0.tar.gz bb-1.2.tar.gz and cc-3.0.tar.gz. I need to build all of them with different configuration options like for the first tarball the configuration option is:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/proxy
```

how to specify this in SPEC file under build or setup macros?

I know for a single source file in tar we can specify ./configure....under %build option but i dont know how to build 3 different source files and build them with different configuration.

How do you recommend keeping these 3 different tar balls in SOURCE directory of rpmbuild:

1. As one tar ball containing 3 of them
2. 3 different tar balls as 3 sources in SOURCE directory

Answer (score 1):

RPM spec files handle multiple source tarballs using SouurceN: directives and the %setup directive can create a parent directory and do a chdir before untiring multiple sources as easily as untarring into multiple separate directories.

So the answer to your question is that either 1) or 2) can be done.